# Can I use one repository interface to make calls to multiple entity tables using Spring JPA?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a scenario where I need to fetch data from 20 tables in an Oracle database. I have 20 entity classes and I am using Spring JPA for getting data. I am using Simple Crud operation for getting data like 
{

```
public interface Object1Repository extends CrudRepository<Object1, Long> {

  List<Object1> findAll();
}
```

}

same for table2
{

```
public interface Object2Repository extends CrudRepository<Object2, Long> {

  List<Object2> findAll();
}
```

}

and so on for table3, table4 etc...

So my question is do I need to create 20 such interface repositories to fetch data from database or is there a better way of doing it something like:

{

```
public interface CommonRepository extends CrudRepository<GenericObject, Long> {

  List<Object1> findAll();
  List<Object2> findAll();
  List<Object3> findAll();
  List<Object4> findAll();
  ...
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to use Spring Data interfaces, you have to create one for each entity, that's how it is intended to be used. If there is a better way, depends on your usecase. But that information is missing in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a repository interface for each entity, and move the logic of querying the 20 tables to your `@Service` component which will act as a "Business Service Facade". You can annotate your method with `@Transactionl` to if you want to query all together, or non if one query fails.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned, you'll have to create each `repository` for each `entity`.

But you can call all the tables in one request if you connect the `entities` between them using `JPA` relations: `@OneToMany`, `@ManyToOne`, `@ManyToMany` or `@OneToOne`